# Check if file is not directory

Tags: c

I currently have a code that checks whether a file is a directory or not, it goes as follows;

```
          file = readdir (dir);
          if(file->d_type & DT_DIR){
          \* some code*\
          }
```

I was wondering, what is the if statement for the exact opposite of this. Something along the line "if file is not directory".

Comment: the `&` in the `if` statement is not necessarily correct due to possible bit pattern overlap with other file types.  Suggest not assuming that DT_DIR is unique,  Rather use: `if(file->d_type == DT_DIR){`   Then asking if it is not a directory would be: `if(file->d_type != DT_DIR){`  I.E. a single character change

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any boolean expression can be negated with the *not* operator (`!`):

```
if (!(file->d_type & DT_DIR)) {
```

Comment: Oh dear that simple. Thank you though.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your question, you can do it this way:

```
 if(!(file->d_type & DT_DIR)){}
```

Comment: Could you explain *why*  you'd want to use *logical and*, rather than *bitwise and* here?

Comment: bitwise `&` operator is different from the logical `&&`

Comment: So, the code talks about file exists or not, so I assumed d_type and DT_DIR are holding boolean values True or False so I went with logical notation. You could have gone for bitwise too as it is just 0 and 1 but I followed the general method of using logical in an if statement.

Comment: @Sharath: Maybe you should read the manpage for `readdir()` on linux?

Answer (score 2):

You can check if the expression evaluates to false:

```
      file = readdir (dir);
      if( (file->d_type & DT_DIR) == 0 ){
      \* some code*\
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

Bitwise & will match to DT_SOCK = 12, and DT_WHT = 14 as well ... if to check only directory... should use "=="

```
 file = readdir (dir);
          if(file->d_type == DT_DIR){
          \* some code*\
          }
```

Reverse:

```
 file = readdir (dir);
          if(file->d_type != DT_DIR){
          \* some code*\
          }
```

You can put negation on any conditional block to reverse it, you already know now..

Comment: This is not the same as the question. The OP is about the `&`.

Comment: & will match to DT_SOCK = 12, and DT_WHT = 14
 as well ... if to check only directory... should use ==